# How to implement shr instructions using lea instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

If I write code like `lea eax, [2 * eax] ; eax * 2` is the same as `shl eax, 1 ; eax * 2`

My question is:

1. How to implement the `shr` instruction? like `lea eax, [2 ... eax]` ?
2. If possible, are there certain tricks?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz probably because `shl` instruction are alternative to `mul` instruction

Comment: They don't behave exactly the same, especially with respect to behaviour on overflow and flags.  You can't simulate shr with lea.

Comment: The addressing modes are meant to facilitate common memory access computations.  It is very common to multiply by 2 or 4 (and add a base), for array element accesses.  `shr`, on the other hand, does division by a power of 2 -- this is unheard of for memory accesses, so the designers don't support that as part of addressing computations.

Comment: I think it could have been possible with ARM `rbit`

Answer (score 5):

You can't emulate a right shift in terms of a left shift, sorry.  (The scale factor in x86 addressing modes is encoded in machine code as a 2-bit shift count from 0 to 3.)

Also note that LEA doesn't set FLAGS, SHL does.

AFAIK there are no tricks, not even inefficient ones.  This problem has come up before for toy ISAs without a right shift; you typically need something like a lookup table or a way to shift bits from one register into another, like `add eax,eax` / `adc edx,edx` to move a bit from the top of EAX to the bottom of EDX.  Starting with EDX=0 and repeating that in a loop for the right number of iterations (32-n or something) will give the same result as a right shift by `n`.

SHR / SAR are pretty necessary primitive operations that can't easily be emulated in terms of anything else.  (Except for right-rotate + zeroing high bits by generating an AND mask.)

Right shift is division by a power of 2.  Division is hard; unlike left-shift / multiplication, you can't build it out of other things easily.  e.g. `add eax,eax` shifts left by 1 because carry propagates from low to high in addition.